# How to resolve "One or more field types are not installed properly" Error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio-2012

I have an SP 2010 Visual Studio 2012/13 solution that creates Site Columns and a document library.  The site columns are created correctly since I can see and verify them.  The problem I have is with the library I created, which references these site columns, gives me an error when I deploy the solution.  If I set the "Deployment Conflict Resolution" of the library to **Automatic**, everything works fine.  If I set the value to **None**, I get:

> Error 33  Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': One or
>   more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings
>   page to delete these fields.

If I have data in this library, I don't want it dropped and recreated each time; nothing is being changed.  The Site Columns are not being changed so I can't figure out what the problem is.  The only other thing I did was to delete the content types that I wasn't using for this library.  The feature that the error references has all the site columns as well as the library and a web part.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to get past this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked for this issue in ULS Logs? (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS)

Comment: Thank you Alexander.  I checked the log and the error was referring to another list.  Not the one I thought I was having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are deploying your List Instance by declaratively (i.e. in elements.xml).
I would suggest to switch to a programmatic provisioning of your List Instance, so that you have full control of the behavior if the list already exists.

**The steps to programmatically add a list instance would be:**

- Add a Feature Receiver for your provisioning Feature
- Edit the "Feature Activated" event receiver with code that:
- If the list doesn't exist, create it
- If the list already exists, do not delete and recreate
- You can "selectively" update the list if it already exists, adding/modifying the fields it has, views, etc.

Basically the idea is that you have full control on how the deployment occurs if you switch to a programmatic approach.

Related question: [Programmatically creating a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18859/programmatically-creating-a-list)

**That being said, if you are sticking with declarative deployment:**

- Are you creating a Content Type that "bundles" the site columns to the list?
- My recommendation would be:
- Create a Content Type that inherits from Document
- Have it include the custom Site Columns that you already created
- Include the Content Type reference in the List Definition
- All of this, instead of directly adding the fields to the list, without "wrapping" them in a Content Type

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728096%28v=office.14%29.aspx